# QML saving last state of the page when navigated to the different page

Tags: qt, qml

I have an application that has different tabs under hamburger button. Let's assume that I draw some polylines on the map page, then I navigated to the settings page. When I come back to my page that should has polylines, it starts from scratch (all of the changes are gone). So how do I prevent this situation? Need help

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: put each tab content in its own item and enable/disable the visibility of other tabs contents based on the one that is currently selected.